# Optimize a MAX aggregated query involving various tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, aggregate-functions

I have some tables that are more or less like this (I'll use a simpler domain so the explanation is clearer):

```
Trades
----------
ID
Seller_ID
Trade_Date

Sellers
-------
ID
Department_ID
```

And I want to get the latest trade made by each department. The query is something like:

```
SELECT Department_ID, MAX(Trade_Date) FROM 
Trades, Sellers
WHERE Trades.Seller_ID = Sellers.ID
GROUP BY Sellers.Department_ID
```

The table Trades has an index on the date, so it can be used to speed up the queries, but I noticed that the query runs fast for some departments (hardcoding the id) and very slow for others.

I've deduced that it happens because of the huge difference of volume of trades by each department. The database is doing a sequential scan on the sorted index to get the first occurrence, and those departments that made their latest sell long time ago will need to go very far in the index.

My current solution is storing the latest query results in an auxiliary table, and make the new queries incremental (filtering by the latest date that was already in the auxiliary table). It solves the problem, as the query is run very frequently and now the index scan just needs to take into account a few seconds worth of trades.

But I think there should be a more elegant solution to this. I know that if the aggregation was made by Seller rather than Department, a compound index would definitively help, but I don't think it is allowed to build indices that spawn different tables...

Comment: Have you tried a compound index on Seller_ID and Trade_date? Also, what sort of number of records are in both tables?

Comment: I've checked it, and there's already such index on the current schema. The number is around 3 million trades per week. The query takes a few seconds, but it should be almost instantaneous.

Comment: With that sort of volume of data and query response requirement, your existing approach appears best to me - but someone else may have a better idea...

Comment: What is the use of sellers.department_id, a foreign key into a not-mentioned table, or a candidate key for sellers ? PLEASE add (a fragment of) the relevant table definitions, that will save us a lot of guessing and typeing.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a materialized view or if you use postgres building something like that on your own? If the insert operation are not as time critical as the selects then I would consider going this way.

There is an article about MVs in postgres:

http://tech.jonathangardner.net/wiki/PostgreSQL/Materialized_Views

Comment: Unluckily the inserts are much more important! I wouldn't like to make the insert performance drop too much

Comment: Have you considered something like a job that does that for you (means that the table with the aggreagion result is updated every 30 seconds or seomthing like that)?  I could not find any information about autonomous transactions for postgresql to implement such a functionality directly with a trigger (seems if it does not support something like that). You could also have a look at their notification system: http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/Invoke-trigger-after-commit-td1881023.html